# Resultset of stored procedure contains list of LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<V>

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, java-stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure call in Java:

```
@Autowired
public ScoreDao(DataSource dataSource) {
    setDataSource(dataSource);
    mScoreStoredProcedure = new ScoreStoredProcedure(dataSource);
}

public List<Score> loadAllScore(String pUsername, String pUUID, int pLimit) {
    return mScoreStoredProcedure.execute(pUsername, pUUID, pLimit);
}

private class ScoreStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {
    private static final String SPROC_NAME = "loadUserScore";

    public ScoreStoredProcedure(DataSource datasource) {
        super(datasource, SPROC_NAME);
        declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("#result-set-2", mScoreMapper));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("vusername", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("vuuid", Types.VARCHAR));
        declareParameter(new SqlParameter("vlimit", Types.INTEGER));
        compile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Score> execute(String pUsername, String pUUID, int pLimit){ 
        Map<String,Object> lAllScoreResult = super.execute(pUsername, pUUID, pLimit);
        List<Score> lAllScore = ((List<Score>)lAllScoreResult.get("#result-set-2"));
        return lAllScore; 
    }

}
```

and this mapper class:

```
public class ScoreMapper implements RowMapper<Score> {

private String suffix = "";

@Autowired
private ScoreCreator scoreCreator;

@Autowired
private QuestionMapper questionMapper;

public ScoreMapper(String pSuffix) {
    suffix = pSuffix;
}

public Score mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    Score lScore = scoreCreator.createScore(rs.getLong(suffix+"id"),
            rs.getTimestamp(suffix+"stempel"), rs.getString(suffix+"username"),
            rs.getInt(suffix+"points"), rs.getInt(suffix+"level"),
            rs.getString(suffix+"comment"),
            questionMapper.mapRow(rs, rowNum), rs.getString(suffix+"uuid"));
    return lScore;
}
  }
```

The problem I have is that the result of my `StoredProcedure` is never cast to `List<Score>`.

Instead it contains a List of `LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap<V>`. Each entry covers a value from the database.

The mapper is correctly wired via Spring.

Briefly: I expect as result a `List<Score>`. I thought I handle this with the methods shown in the code. How can I cast the result directly to my `List<Score>`?

I followed this tutorial http://www.jtmelton.com/2007/10/30/using-springs-storedprocedure-and-rowmapper-mechanisms/

Could you help me find the problem?

Comment: It looks like you are never calling mapRow, you are just casting the map to a list.

Comment: Yes Iam wondering about that too but I followed this tutorial http://www.jtmelton.com/2007/10/30/using-springs-storedprocedure-and-rowmapper-mechanisms/

Comment: Ah ok.  Well scratch what I said about calling mapRow, this should only be used by the spring api.

Comment: If you post the code where you call the execute, that may be helpful.  The posted code seems to be correct according to the tutorial.

Comment: which execute do you mean? I posted the StoredProcedure execute already.

Comment: The code you are creating an instance of ScoreStoredProcedure from, and then calling execute on it.

Comment: Are you getting an exception when you run this?

Comment: no. I just expect that spring does the work for me and casts the result to List<Score>

Comment: How are you able to tell that the code is not working correctly?  If it is able to cast to List<Score> I'd say it is working.

Comment: I would expect a list of score as result. But I get a list of LinkedCaseSensitiveMap. Thats a fact. If I try to cast one of these maps I got a ClassCastException.

Comment: Btw. I never told you the code is Not working correctly. I just told it works not as I expect

Comment: What is the content of the returned `LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap`s?

Comment: Can you post the stored procedure details?

Comment: Unfortunality not now. Today evening

Comment: Btw. setting the resultset name and mapper is without any effect. Thats the reason why I use the defaultname of the resultset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you rename the result set parameter to, say, "ScoreResultSet"?

So

```
declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("ScoreResultSet", mScoreMapper));
```

and

```
List<Score> lAllScore = ((List<Score>)lAllScoreResult.get("ScoreResultSet"));
```

The name you are currently using also gets used by spring when it auto generates names for result sets.

I think you may therefore now be returning a different, unprocessed, result set than the mapped one from the SqlReturnResultSet parameter you declared.

======

EDIT:

I just found this other question of yours: [Java StoredProcedure with SqlReturnResultSet not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349688/java-storedprocedure-with-sqlreturnresultset-not-working) and assuming that we are talking about the same stored procedure:

I suspect you have two selects in the stored procedure and it returns two result sets.
You should declare two (properly named) SqlReturnResultSet parameters instead of one. The order of the declaration matters, so you cannot declare just one and give it the name usually assigned to the second one.

Comment: You was right. I have 3 selects inside my Sp. Setting the properties in the right ordering leads to the expected result. Thx a lot!

Comment: Please help me with almost same problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/30378061/2323234

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to `LinkedList` rather than `List<Score>`.

The tutorial shows as follows, and is the only thing I can think of that you have done differently from the tutorial:

```
List resultList = (LinkedList)results.get(Constants.RESULTSET);

    //iterate of results list and print
    for (Iterator it=resultList.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        User user1 = (User)it.next();
        System.out.println(user1);
    }

    return resultList;
```

Comment: casting to LinkedList can't help, as LinkedList has  no additional methods the List interface doesn't have